# How to handle communication between different viewModels?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I have an activity that contains a number of fragments. Each fragment has a viewModel scoped to its lifetime with some logic inside. The host activity has a viewModel too, including some code to show a popup-style message.

I want my fragment viewModels to be able to post messages to this popup. However, how could I access the activity-viewModel from inside one of my fragment-viewModels?

I'll write some exemplary Kotlin code, but the question is not specific to Kotlin since it's more of an architectural issue.

```java
class MyActivityViewModel {
    ...
    popupMessage = MutableLiveData<String>("") // is observed by my activity
    fun postMessage(text: String) {
        popupMessage.value = text
    }
}

class MyFragmentAViewModel {
    ...
    fun someFunctionA() {
        // want to call ActivityViewModel's postMessage from here
    }
}
class MyFragmentBViewModel {
    ...
    fun someFunctionB() {
        // want to call ActivityViewModel's postMessage from here too
    }
}
```

I can't easily call `ViewModelProvider` since I'd rather not keep a reference to an Activity in my viewModel. The only direct option I see is to pass the activity-viewModel to the fragment-viewModels through the constructor or an `init()` method. That *should* be safe since the parent viewModel's lifetime should exceed the fragment viewModels' lifetime. I think.

Still, that solution rubs me the wrong way.

Are there any other alternatives? Or perhaps an entirely different approach to the issue?

Comment: Consider using custom data bus for intra-component communication: "observer", or some sort of "producer-consumer" is initiated and handled on the application level. Each ViewModel can subscribe to the bus in the "init" and unsubscribe in "onCleared". The data is sent to anyone by anyone, you only have to find a way how to filter the data out (by some flag, or type, or whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the thought of a greenhorn:

Can't you tell the activity that your fragment wants to use its method?

If you

1. Make an interface with a method a la "fragmentAWantsToUsePostMessage" in your fragment
2. Implement the interface in the activity, so that every time fragmentAWantsToUsePostMessage is called, the activity calls  postMessage
3. Get a reference to the implementation of the interface in your fragment
4. Use that reference when the fragment needs to call "post message"

Shouldn't that work? Or is that against your "not keeping a reference"?
As I said: I'm new to all of this, so I might be completely wrong.

I can see that there's a post on medium that might be relevant: [How to Communicate between Fragment and Activity](https://medium.com/@m.elrasheid/how-to-communicate-between-fragment-and-activity-22fef9213535)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I could work with a callback but that seems to be rather cumbersome. Basically it would go like this: `FragmentViewModel decides it wants to post a message -> FragmentViewModel puts it in a liveData object -> Fragment receives this data and notifies the activity via callback -> Activity notifies its viewModel -> viewModel does its thing and puts the result in another liveData -> Finally, activity receives this lifeData and displays the message`. That's a lot of steps just to get a piece of info from one class to another.